# What does $k(C)$ denote where $C$ is a curve? (link to context included)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

On page 5 of http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/bagsrr.pdf is says that "A repartition is an indexed set $\lbrace r _{P}\rbrace_{P\in C}$ where $\lbrace r _{P}\rbrace$ is an element of $k(C)$, and
$\lbrace r _{P}\rbrace\in\mathcal{O}_{P}$ for all but finitely many $P$", however, I can't seem to find what $k(C)$ is. Does anyone know?

Comment: It's on the same line that you quoted from: "recall  that  an  element  of
$k(C)$ is regular at all but  finitely many points of $C$"

Comment: But what exactly are the elements? We only know the elements are regular or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: From the description I quoted it seems these are rational functions on $C$, i.e. densly defined regular maps.

Comment: So is $k(C)$ then just a ring of regular functions?

Comment: No, the ring of rational functions. This is an important difference. Sometimes there are no regular functions, but there are rational functions.

Comment: Ah okay yes sorry of course, all but finitely many elements are regular. I think that make sense, thanks.

Comment: In general though it is not true that rational maps have only finitely many points of non-regularity. This is only true in this case because the only Zariski-closed subsets of a curve are finite.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now, I was wondering about that. Thanks.